# Consolidating bar graph data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here's my bar graph currently:
[image]

I would like to consolidate all the Trump data into one bar, and all the Clinton data into another.

ie

[image]

I think that basically I need to calculate the mean of all values where the winner is Trump, as well as the mean of all values where the winner is Clinton, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that because I'm a noob.

Here's my current code, if it helps:

```
library(ggplot2)

healthd = read.csv("R/states.csv")


states = healthd[[1]]
uninsured2015 = healthd[[3]]
uninsured2015 = abs(as.numeric(as.character(gsub("%","", uninsured2015))))
insuredChange = healthd[[4]]
insuredChange = abs(as.numeric(as.character(gsub("%","", insuredChange))))
winner = healthd[[15]]

ggplot(data = healthd, aes(x = states, y = insuredChange, fill=winner)) +
xlab("State") + ylab("Percent Uninsured (2015)") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Trump" = "red4", "Clinton" = "blue4")) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Also, here's my the head of my data:

```
> head(healthd)
       State Uninsured.Rate..2010. Uninsured.Rate..2015. Uninsured.Rate.Change..2010.2015.
1   Alabama                 14.60%                10.10%                            -4.50%
2    Alaska                 19.90%                14.90%                               -5%
3   Arizona                 16.90%                10.80%                            -6.10%
4  Arkansas                 17.50%                 9.50%                               -8%
5 California                18.50%                 8.60%                            -9.90%
6   Colorado                15.90%                 8.10%                            -7.80%
  Health.Insurance.Coverage.Change..2010.2015. Employer.Health.Insurance.Coverage..2015.
1                                       215000                                   2545000
2                                        36000                                    390000
3                                       410000                                   3288000
4                                       234000                                   1365000
5                                      3826000                                  19552000
6                                       419000                                   2949000
  Marketplace.Health.Insurance.Coverage..2016. Marketplace.Tax.Credits..2016.
1                                       165534                         152206
2                                        17995                          16205
3                                       179445                         124346
4                                        63357                          56843
5                                      1415428                        1239893
6                                       108311                          67062
  Average.Monthly.Tax.Credit..2016. State.Medicaid.Expansion..2016. Medicaid.Enrollment..2013.
1                             $310                            FALSE                     799176
2                             $750                             TRUE                     122334
3                             $230                             TRUE                    1201770
4                             $306                             TRUE                     556851
5                             $309                             TRUE                    7755381
6                             $318                             TRUE                     783420
  Medicaid.Enrollment..2016. Medicaid.Enrollment.Change..2013.2016. Medicare.Enrollment..2016.
1                     910775                                 111599                     989855
2                     166625                                  44291                      88966
3                    1716198                                 514428                    1175624
4                     920194                                 363343                     606146
5                   11843081                                4087700                    5829777
6                    1375264                                 591844                     820234
  X2016.Election.Winner
1                 Trump
2                 Trump
3                 Trump
4                 Trump
5               Clinton
6               Clinton
```

Comment: Use facet? `+facet_wrap(~winner)` or `+facet_grid(~winner)`

Comment: If I do that it says `Error in +facet_grid(~winner) : invalid argument to unary operator` and my graph gets all messed up

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to aggregate your data into a new dataframe first, and replot it. There are lots of ways to do that in R, but probably `dplyr` had the best combination of ease of learning, power, and programming safety - so I will use that.

I dummied up some data, and here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

n <- 50
ss <- sprintf("State-%.2d",1:n)
u15 <- 10*(runif(n) + 0.5)
icg = 4*(runif(n) + 0.5)
w = sample(c("Candidate-1","Candidate-2"),n,replace=T)

healthd <- data.frame(states=ss,uninsured2015=u15,insuredChange=icg,winner=w)

ggplot(data = healthd, aes(x = states, y = insuredChange, fill=winner)) +
  xlab("State") + ylab("Percent Uninsured (2015)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Candidate-1" = "red4", "Candidate-2" = "blue4")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

# make a new aggregated dataframe with dplyr
aghealthd <- healthd %>% group_by(winner) %>% 
                         summarise(uninsured2015=mean(uninsured2015),
                                   insuredChange=mean(insuredChange))

# plot that with the same code, changing only the x-axis
ggplot(data = aghealthd, aes(x = winner, y = insuredChange, fill=winner)) +
  xlab("State") + ylab("Percent Uninsured (2015)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Candidate-1" = "red4", "Candidate-2" = "blue4")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Here is plot 1:

[image]

And here is plot 2:

[image]

Comment: To get accurate countrywide percentages you would need to take weighted means based on the population of the states, the current percentage might be skewed. I realize this isn't in the question or in the example data, so it's not an attack on the answer, but just a note.

Comment: Yeah, maybe one of his columns has that. It is a good point to make as someone will bring it up for sure.